# Why is Envelope noisy even after filtering and achievement of SNR gain (-6dB SNR to 14dB snr)?

Tags: discrete-signals, snr, edge-detection, envelope, pulse

A noisy signal with 500 MHz bandwidth, with negative SNR, when filtered to 6 MHz bandwidth, should attain a theoretical SNR gain of 20 dB. So if the original signal has -6 dB SNR, after filtering we should see the signal above the noise floor because SNR gain results in an attained SNR of +14 dB.

The signal was filtered with an FIR filter of order 511 (a Hamming window of length 512 was applied). The SNR was expected to increase in terms of bandwidth reduction and consequently noise reduction.

The goal was to compare 2 envelopes at comparable power levels:

1. A signal generated at 14 dB SNR and
2. A filtered signal (originally at -6 dB SNR), that should theoretically achieve an SNR of 14 dB after filtering.

For both signals, the signal power was kept constant, at -36 dBm.
The noise power was set at -50 dBm for the 14dB SNR signal and -30 dBm for the -6dB SNR signal. That's the reason why envelopes in the following image appear to have the same level/amplitude.

My question is: why is the -6dB signal envelope still noisy even after filtering, although the SNR is +14db whereas the 14 dB signal envelope is smooth even without filtering?

An image of SNR figures has also been attached , which quantifies the signal's SNR at generation and after filtering

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Khadija Pirzada and welcome to Signal Processing SE. Would you care to share some more information as to how the signal was filtered, why do you expect the increase in the SNR and anything else that would help people answer your question?

Comment: signal was filtered through an FIR filter of order 511(hamming window of length 512 was applied).  SNR was expected to increase in terms of bandwidth reduction and consequently noise reduction in direct relation

Comment: Your figure is unclear -- according to the legend each plot has a 14dB SNR.  "14dB SNR archieved after filtering" not only has a different noise level (which looks like roughly 14dB to me), it does not center on the one marked "14dB before filtering".  Much as I hate dredging through code, could you please _edit your question_ to show us how you generated these plots, as concisely as possible.

Comment: Respected TimWescott, I have now edited my question, and I hope it is free of any any further ambiguity for you to understand it more effectively this time. let me know :)

Comment: You say "A signal generated at 14 dB SNR", but what you really have is a signal that you _believe_ has been generated at 14dB SNR.  Please _show us the code_ that generated that signal.

Comment: Generated signal's SNR was quantified, using the SNR function in MATLAB.
for now, I'm attaching the SNR figures in my question, and will upload the code later, after a bit of tweaking .